# Is redis essential to use actioncable in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I made live chat using actioncable. This works perfectly locally. However, heroku's view / page does not render.
Is redis essential for heroku to work?

I also wrote the code in product.rb

```
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['https://my-url-45158.herokuapp.com', 'http://my-url-45158.herokuapp.com']
config.web_socket_server_url = "wss://my-url-45158.herokuapp.com/cable"
```

Comment: Does your application use Redis? What kind of data storages does it use?

Comment: My heroku has pg add-on. And I did not use redis in my application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

afaik yes it is, see this,

https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable

and this

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#configuration

when in production mode rails use redis for its subscription adapter.
as written in the documentation
`by default redis for production and async for development and test environments`

beside that there is PostgreSQL Adapter and Async Adapter(but should not be used for production)

Comment: I did not use redis in my application. And the production configuration on your link is already there, including pg. should I install redis in my app to use it in Heroku?

Comment: yes you should set it up, install it in heroku, add it in your gemfile(production env), and give the correct address to the database.yml production, have you read this part? https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable#deploying-our-application-to-heroku

Comment: Heroku has multiple Redis addons. Heroku Redis, Redis to go, Redis Cloud and OpenRedis. What is the difference if I choose one over the other? Does it change anything about adding redis url to `cable.yml` and do I keep `gem redis` for all of these or it's different for every addon?